# section header for UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm subclassing `UICollectionViewLayout`.

`UITableView` sectionHeader stays around when scrolled down.
(You can see this when you scroll down the contacts list, section header(A, B, C..) stays around until next section header takes its place.

I'd like to add a section header to my `UICollectionView` but don't know how to do this.

Comment: I'm having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511733/how-to-make-supplementary-view-float-in-uicollectionview-as-section-headers-do-i thinking you have to implement your own `UICollectionViewLayout` for this.