# How to create a 'sticky' footer for a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

What is the best method to provide a footer for a `UICollectionView` that "sticks" to the bottom of the screen bounds on a given page? Assume the `UICollectionView` is full screen and only has one section.

Currently I am providing a `UICollectionReusableView` object in `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:`, but (as one might expect) when the content of my collection exceeds this screen's bounds, the footer is pushed off-screen.

I'm guessing the key is a *Decoration View* - but I can't find any good code (non-IB) examples on how these work, and Apple's documentation is in my opinion unclear on this particular subject.

**Update re: Decoration Views**

After building out and experimenting with a *Decoration View* ([using this tutorial](http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/decorationviews/)), I hit some limitations - namely that there aren't really any callbacks between the *Decoration View* object and your `UICollectionViewController` controller object (the *Decoration View* is managed by a `UICollectionViewLayout` object, not the `UICollectionViewController` object). It seems Apple was very serious about *Decoration Views* being limited to visual adornments, and not data-driven (although you could obviously hack around this).

So, the "right" solution still eludes me, but in the mean time I just created a static `UIView` object and am just managing that from my `UICollectionViewController` object. It works OK, but feels wrong.

**Update re: Sticky HEADERS**

Over the last few months, I've worked on similar issues across various projects, and did recently find a solution for sticky HEADERS. I assume the same would apply to footers, but I haven't tested it.

Details about headers here:

[How to make Supplementary View float in UICollectionView as Section Headers do in UITableView plain style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511733/how-to-make-supplementary-view-float-in-uicollectionview-as-section-headers-do-i)

The implementation is pretty heavy, but it seems to work well in most circumstances.

If there is no further activity on this question soon, I will close as a duplicate and point to the article above.

Answer (score 17):

Basically what you need to do is provide a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass that invalidates itself when the bounds change (when the view scrolls the bounds change). And then provides `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for the supplementary view where the center is updated to hug the current bounds of the collection view (top, bottom, left, right, whatever).

I added project on [github](https://github.com/derrh/StickyViews) that demonstrates this strategy.

**UPDATE:** as of iOS 9, `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` has two very handy properties that simplify this task drastically. See `sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds` and `sectionFootersPinToVisibleBounds`.

Comment: @pxlshpr it shouldn't be, this is super inefficient

Comment: Inefficient or not, invalidating the layout when bounds change is exactly how Apple appears to have implemented the iOS 9 pinning. `invalidateLayout` is called several times per second when scrolling with pinning turned on.

Answer (score 0):

ok.. so I have tried updating code from below link. and it works.
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/add-sticky-footer-to-uicollectionview-in-swift

```
class StickyFooter : UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

var footerIsFound             : Bool = false
var UICollectionAttributes    : [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?


override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}


override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?
{
    UICollectionAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

    for  attributes in UICollectionAttributes! {

        if let type = attributes.representedElementKind {

            if type == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter
            {
                footerIsFound = true
                updateFooter(attributes: attributes)
            }
        }
    }

    if (!self.footerIsFound) {

        let newItem = self.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, at : NSIndexPath(row: self.UICollectionAttributes!.count, section: 0) as IndexPath)


        UICollectionAttributes?.append(newItem!)

    }

    return UICollectionAttributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
{
    let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: elementKind, with: indexPath)

    attributes.size = CGSize(width: self.collectionView!.bounds.size.width, height: 75)

    if elementKind.isEqualToString(find: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter)
    {
        updateFooter(attributes: attributes)
    }
    return attributes
}


func updateFooter(attributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes){
    let currentBounds = self.collectionView?.bounds
    attributes.zIndex = 1024
    attributes.isHidden = false
    let yOffset = currentBounds!.origin.y + currentBounds!.size.height - attributes.size.height/2.0
    attributes.center = CGPoint(x: currentBounds!.midX, y: yOffset)

}}
```

Comment: assign class StickyFooter to your collectionviewflow layout

Answer (score -6):

UICollectionViewController (like UITableVC) is a "shortcut", these 2 classes are just overriding UIViewController, create the collectionView for you.

You can easily do that and add your sticky view on your own.

Comment: I have learned more about this over the course of various projects in the last few months (since posting this question), and IMHO this is far, far from easy. I will update my original question for future searchers, but if you know of an easy way to accomplish the above, please elaborate.