# UICollectionView scroll single column

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a problem, it is not so much about a bug, but rather how to approach the issue.
I wanna create a UICollectionViewLayout where I can scroll a single column. Normally when 
we scroll a scroll view, all the subviews scroll up/down/left/right. But here I wanna have a set of columns, and basically as user scrolls vertically, I want to only scroll that column and leave the others where they were. More over if the user scrolls horizontally I want the normal behavior, that is, all columns scroll left or right.

Any idea how to approach this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late, but, better late than ever!

You are right in that you need to rock your own UICollectionViewLayout. I recommend you start with having it work normally before you start working on your particular behaviour.

Basically what you want to do is have all cells but one column be vertically sticky.

To achieve that, you need reposition all your cells (but the ones that actually move) based on the Collection View's xOffset and yOffset.

Checkout my answer on this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20987008/322377

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use a UITableView with custom UITableViewCell containing UIScrollView and you can set scrollview to scroll in desired direction.

Comment: Scrolling columns not rows.

Comment: Oopps! for this you can use one UIScrollView filling the screen along with multiple UIScrollViews (like columns) in it as its subviews.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd rather use a UICollectionView as its suited for collections.

Comment: ok so you can customize collection view cell to be of height equal to device height and make UIScrollView as a subview of it.