# iOS: CollectionView stick header while scrolling

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am implementing CollectionView with custom layout. It have vertical scrolling.
I want to make that some cells will be sticked  to the top while scrolling like section header in tableView.

The idea is to create day collectionView with time. And while user will be scroll thought time the current hour will be sticked to the top(if it will be not visible and hidden by top). It will be only if the current hour hidden by top, not by bottom. And the other items should be scrollable like usual.
I think that I should not use supplementaryViews here

Is it possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange` so it returns `YES`. This means `layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind` and `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` are called when the `UICollectionView` is scrolled, and in there you can then calculate proper frames for your views, including the sticky views. If you have a complicated `UICollectionView`, this may lead to bad performance, but as far as I know it's the easiest way to do this for now. Your other bet is looking at invalidation contexts, but they're quite badly documented. If you still want to experiment with those, you could take a look at [Using Invalidation Contexts for UICollectionViewLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100680/using-invalidation-contexts-for-uicollectionviewlayout)

Comment: ok, thanks for your response, so for holding sticky cell I need to use SupplementaryView?

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to go. This guide is pretty good at explaining it: http://dativestudios.com/blog/2015/01/10/collection_view_sticky_headers/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `UICollectionView`'s `supplementaryView`.

> [Apple's Collection View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html)

Comment: oh, thanks for you answer, but  I think that will be not that I need, I updated my question with more details