# Auto Layout in UICollectionViewCell not working

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I have a simple UICollectionView with cells that have a single UITextView. The UITextView is constrained to the edges of the cell, so they should stay the same size as the cell size.

The problem I'm having is that for some reason these constraints are not working when I specify the cell size via collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:.

I have the cell size set to 320x50 in the Storyboard. If I return a size with 2 times the height of the cell size with sizeForItemAtIndexPath:, the UITextView stays the same height despite the constraints I set. I am using Xcode 6 GM.

My view controller code is:

```
@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionView.delegate = self;
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UICollectionViewCell *c = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]];

    NSLog(@"%f", c.frame.size.height);

    UITextView *tv = (UITextView *)[c viewWithTag:9];
    NSLog(@"%f", tv.frame.size.height);

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)collectionView.collectionViewLayout;

    CGSize size = flowLayout.itemSize;

    size.height = size.height * 2;

    return size;
}

@end
```

Those logs in viewDidAppear: give me an output of:

100.00000

50.00000

As you can see, the UITextView height doesn't change with the cell height.

Here's a screenshot of the storyboard I set up with a UITextView constrained in the UICollectionViewCell:

[image]

I know using auto layout constraints works fine with UITableViewCells and dynamic resizing. I have no idea why it's not working in this case. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Well, I just looked on the iOS developer forums. Apparently, this is a bug with the iOS 8 SDK running on iOS 7 devices. The workaround is to add the following to your subclass of UICollectionViewCell:

```c
- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    [super setBounds:bounds];
    self.contentView.frame = bounds;
}
```

```swift
override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
      contentView.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Great ! you save my day ! this solution working for me after installing iOS 8 xcode 6 etc. all my tableview didn't adapt the uicollectionview cell size.
Thank you :)

Comment: in case it didn't work for you try this: awakerFromNib(){ contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight }

Comment: I had same issue on iPad with iOS 8, and this solution fixed the problem as well. Thanks!

Comment: +1 on this being an issue in iOS 8 too. I had a collection view cell that was working fine in iOS 7, but not in iOS 8. This fixed it.

Comment: Totally forgot about this.  Thanks...still an issue with latest iOS 8 SDK running on iOS 7 devices.

Comment: I have faced with the same issue on iOS 9, Does it still not fixed?

Comment: Still happening on iOS 14.. and the above fixed it. Scrolling to item offset my custom view (as if auto layout was ignored) for some reason, and invalidate flow layout didn't work. Can't believe this is still happening many years later.

Answer (score 42):

Equivalent Swift Code :

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
      contentView.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is helpful, but is simply a translation of the accepted answer. That's probably what the person who down voted this answer thought.

Comment: It really helped me...Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I'm using iOS 10 with a custom UICollectionViewLayout where I calculate the cell size. Autolayout wasn't working and this fixed it

Answer (score 25):

Here is the solution, if you are not subclassing `UICollectionViewCell`. Just add this two lines under your `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` after `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:`

Obj-C

```
[[cell contentView] setFrame:[cell bounds]];
[[cell contentView] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Swift - 2.0

```
cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
```

Comment: For me it worked without adding second line from the code

Comment: If your app suports multiple orientation, then u will need second line also. :-)  @Teena nath Paul

Answer (score 4):

Swift 2.0:

```
cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
```

Comment: Added this to `cellForItemAt`and nothing changed :(