# How to re-layout collectionview cell once it has proper sizing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview where I'm trying to do 2 cells on each row. It looks like it's building the cells from my prototype cell and centering everything properly. Then it runs my sizeForItemAtIndexPath and makes the sizing correct (2 cells per row), but then all the labels are off center as it was laid it before.

I have been screwing with invalidateLayout and viewDidLayoutSubviews but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas how to force the cell to re-layout the labels after it has run sizeForItemAtIndexPath? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here are two images.
This is the first image sizeForItemAtIndexPath is commented out, everything in the cell is formatted perfectly, but the spacing is off:
[image]
Here is the second, with the sizeForItemAtIndexPath making the collectionView have proper spacing. Here is where the alignment is messed up within the cell, not centered.
[image]

Comment: Could you just use constraints to lay out the subviews in your cells?

Comment: I have it laid out in the prototype cell of the collectionview, everything is constrained to the center. It just seems to build the cell, and then size it, so everything is off center.

Comment: some screenshots would really help. I might have a solution to this, if I know exactly what you are trying to do. Also check this to see if it helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472956/ios-uicollectionview-dynamically-change-cells-height/33266661#33266661

Comment: I added 2 photos on what is happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the experience of the `contentView` not resizing correctly in my cells when they are changed to a different size than is present in the storyboard with collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:).  Try adding the following after you dequeue your cell:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
```

If you're using a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` you can put that code in an override of `awakeFromNib()`:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    contentView.frame = cell.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
}
```

Comment: You are the MAN Charles! This works like a charm, much appreciated!

Comment: It'd be nice if Apple fixed this, but at least the workaround is easy once you know what the problem is.