# UICollectionViewCell subclass incorrect size when modifying underlying layout constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

[image: UICollectionView Flow Layout Inner Constraints]

I have a `UICollectionView` that uses flow layout and dynamic-width cells defined in a xib. The xib has constraints on all sides of a stack view that contains a dynamic label and a static image. These constraints should change based on the margins provided in `configureCell(cellData:, padding:)`, which is called on `cellForItemAt` and `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` datasource/delegate methods. Unfortunately, the sizes returned by `systemLayoutSizeFitting()` are incorrect if I change the constraints to something else in `configureCell(cellData:, padding:)`.

[image: UICollectionViewCell xib subclass]

I've tried `setNeedsLayout()`, `layoutIfNeeded()`, `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()`, `updateConstraintsIfNeeded()` in every combination I can think of.  I have also tried [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25804588/auto-layout-in-uicollectionviewcell-not-working) without success.

How does one update constraints inside a `UICollectionViewCell` and have it size properly in `collectionView(collectionView:, layout:, sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)`?

`UICollectionViewDataSource`:

```
private var _sizingViewCell: LabelCollectionViewCell!

//registers and init's sizing cell...

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    _sizingViewCell.configureCell(self.cellData[indexPath.row], padding: defaultItemPadding)
    var size = _sizingViewCell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    return size
}
```

`UICollectionViewCell` subclass:

```
func configureCell(_ cellData: LabelCollectionCellData, padding: UIEdgeInsets? = nil) {
    removeButton.isHidden = cellData.removable
    if let padding = padding {
        leadingPaddingConstraint.constant = padding.left
        topPaddingConstraint.constant = padding.top
        trailingPaddingConstraint.constant = padding.right
        bottomPaddingConstraint.constant = padding.bottom

        contentStackView.spacing = padding.left
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be operator error.

I was giving `configureCell(cellData:, padding:)` a different padding in:

`collectionView(_ collectionView:, cellForItemAt indexPath:)`

than I was giving in:

`collectionView(collectionView:, layout collectionViewLayout:, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:)`

Which caused the views to not display correctly.