# UICollectionView set a header view similar to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using a `UICollectionViewController` and would like to set a `headerView` (not a section header view) at the top of the `collectionView`, similar to how you can set the `tableViewHeader` for a `UITableView`.

So far, I have found nothing about this.

Is it not possible?

Answer (score -2):

`UICollectionView` has a `SupplementaryView`.

You can register a view with

```
- (void)registerClass:(Class)viewClass forSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind withReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind withReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

and use with :

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

If you want a fixed header like `UITableViewStylePain`, check the below link.

[How to make Supplementary View float in UICollectionView as Section Headers do in UITableView plain style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511733/how-to-make-supplementary-view-float-in-uicollectionview-as-section-headers-do-i)

Comment: But you seem to be talking about section headers. I just want one header at the top of the `UICollectionView` just like `UITableView` provides with `tableViewHeaderView`.

Comment: Subclassing `UICollectionViewLayout` must be the only answer. You can customize almost every thing with it.