# How to make all items in a section of a UICollectionView float over the scroll view?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, constraints, uicollectionviewcell

I want the items of one `section` in a `UICollectionView` to remain stationary while the rest of the items inside the `UICollectionView` are being scrolled.

I tried to achieve this by setting `Autolayout` `constraint` that pin the items to the `superview` of the `UICollectionView`. However, this does not seem to work because the `constraints` complain about `UICollectionViewCell` and the `UICollectionView's` `superview` not having a common ancestor.

Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Use another view.. Don't add it in collection view.

Comment: The problem is the user needs to be able to drag and drop items from one section to another. Introducing another view makes it much harder to do so

Comment: Did you try using header for collection view? A floating header can be implemented as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511733/how-to-make-supplementary-view-float-in-uicollectionview-as-section-headers-do-i)

Comment: This approach seems to only work for supplementary views (headers and footers) but I need the actual UICollectionView items to remain stationary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ad-J's comment I was able to implement the solution.

I needed to override `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and implement the following methods:

```
override func prepareLayout() {
    super.prepareLayout()

    //fill layoutInfo of type [NSIndexPath:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
    //with layoutAttributes you need in your layout

    if let cv = self.collectionView {
        for (indexPath, tileToFloat) in layoutInfo {
            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                var origin = tileToFloat.frame.origin
                origin.y += cv.contentOffset.y + cv.contentInset.top
                tileToFloat.frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: tileToFloat.size)
            }
            tileToFloat.zIndex = 1
        }
    }
}

override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

This will make all items in the first section stationary.