# TableView cells with collectionView performance issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tableview

I have the following layout:[image]
When scrolling the tableView fps drops to around 25 and it becomes very jittering.

I think it's my implementation of the collectionView since a lot of operations are performed in cellForIndexAtPath. But I can't see what can be optimized?

```
extension MyTableViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    // No sections are longer than 99
    if(collectionView.tag < 100)
    {
        let code = codes0[collectionView.tag].objectForKey("code") as! String

        return code.componentsSeparatedByString(",").count
    }
    else if(collectionView.tag < 200)
    {
        let code = codes1[collectionView.tag-100].objectForKey("code") as! String

        return code.componentsSeparatedByString(",").count
    }
    else
    {
        let code = codes2[collectionView.tag-200].objectForKey("code") as! String

        return code.componentsSeparatedByString(",").count
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("code", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCodeCollectionViewCell

    // Read that this should help for GPU
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    var codeLength:String! = ""

    if(collectionView.tag < 100)
    {
        codeLength = self.codes0[collectionView.tag].objectForKey("code") as! String
    }
    else if(collectionView.tag < 200)
    {
        codeLength = self.codes1[collectionView.tag-100].objectForKey("code") as! String
    }
    else
    {
        codeLength = self.codes2[collectionView.tag-200].objectForKey("code") as! String
    }

    let cLength = codeLength.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

    if(indexPath.row <= cLength.count)
    {
        cell.imageCode.image = UIImage(named: cLength[indexPath.row])
    }

    return cell
}
```

**My tableView looks like:**

Here's the collectionView data source and delegate set

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cheat") as! CodeTableViewCell

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(self, forRow: indexPath.row, forSection: indexPath.section)

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: CodeTableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    switch indexPath.section
    {
    case 2:
        cell.name = codes2[indexPath.row].objectForKey("name") as! String

        cell.descript = ((codes2[indexPath.row].objectForKey("description") as! String).isEmpty ? "-" : codes2[indexPath.row].objectForKey("description") as! String)

    case 1:
        cell.name = codes1[indexPath.row].objectForKey("name") as! String

        cell.descript = ((codes1[indexPath.row].objectForKey("description") as! String).isEmpty ? "-" : codes1[indexPath.row].objectForKey("description") as! String)

    default:
        cell.name = codes0[indexPath.row].objectForKey("name") as! String

        cell.descript = ((codes0[indexPath.row].objectForKey("description") as! String).isEmpty ? "-" : codes0[indexPath.row].objectForKey("description") as! String)
    }
}
```

Comment: Going by one look of the code,i think, its due to to many checks in the cellForRow... method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking briefly at your code, it seams like you would be fine with only an `UICollectionView` setup that makes use of `UICollectionReusableView` as *headers*. That way all the `collectionViews` would reuse the same `cells` and you don't have to layout the `collectionViews` each time a `UITableViewCell` becomes visible.

[image: Interface Builder setup]

Also you might consider **storing the results** of operations such as `code.componentsSeparatedByString(",").count` in separate variables, and only calculate it once your data is changed.

Comment: Yes I understand but since I have to use UICollectionReusableView as headers wouldn't I have to create a custom one if I need "global" headers to stick below navigationBar?

Comment: I see. I must say I mist that in my first look at your setup. There are ways of doing this, as referred in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33960962/2614339), how ever you would have to implement the intermediate headers as `custom cells`.
Before trying anything else, have you tried loading your **images** on a *background thread*?

Comment: Doesn't UIImage along with anything UI related has to be set on the main thread? Since I'm not downloading anything but only assinging the image this shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: You are right that the updating of the UI has to be done on the _main thread_, but the line `cell.imageCode.image = UIImage(named: cLength[indexPath.row])` is both loading the image, and then assigning it to the cell. Try to comment that part out and see if you experience any improvement. If you do, the following adjustment might be helpful:
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
 let image = UIImage(named: cLength[indexPath.row])
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  cell.imageCode.image = image
 })
})`

Comment: I've tried that and for iOS 10 it works great but not for devices below?

Comment: Is that a question if it works for lower versions or why it is not working for lower versions? If the second, what is not working?

Comment: I'm wondering why fps can vary that much. On an iPhone 6 with iOS 9 it runs with 33 fps, but for the same device yet with iOS 10 it runs with 59-60 fps?